# Apply anchor tag to all the h3 tag under a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to find a way to add a anchor tag to all h3 tag.The content is dynamic in nature .

I want to add dynamic anchor tag for all the h3 tags only

```
<div class="class1">
    <h2>Main heading</h2>
    <h3>Heading1</h3>
    <h1>some content1</h1>
    <h3>Heading2</h3>
    <h1>some content2</h1>
    <h3>Heading3</h3>
    <h1>some content3</h1>
</div>
```

I tried below Jquery code but its creating nothing

```
$("h3.class1").append('<h3>');
var al = $("h3.class1 >");

al.append('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Comment: use al.each(function(i,e){ $(this).append('<a ....');});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.class1 h3').each(function (){
            $(this).wrap('<a />');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.class1 h3').wrap('<a />');
```

This will `wrap` all the `h3` inside `.class1` by `anchor` tag.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tb0664L6/)

Answer (score 2):

Try [wrapInner()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner)

```js
$('.class1 h3').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <h2>Main heading</h2>
  <h3>Heading1</h3>
  <h1>some content1</h1>
  <h3>Heading2</h3>
  <h1>some content2</h1>
  <h3>Heading3</h3>
  <h1>some content3</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.html()` callback function to achieve this:

> function
>   Type: Function( Integer index, htmlString oldhtml ) => htmlString
>   A function returning the HTML content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old HTML value as arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

```
$('.class1 h3').html(function(i,oldhtml){
  return '<a href="#">'+ oldhtml +'</a>' ; 
});
```